# Can we use `gsub` to capture a substring (grouped by continuously repeated characters) and replace it with its reverse, in a REGEX way?

Tags: r, regex, string, replace, gsub

I am trying to explore the capability of regex to capture a substring grouped by continuously repeated characters and replace it with its reverse, but **using `gsub` only**.

For example, given a string `s <- "abxxxyyyyzzpqr"`, where `"xxxyyyyzz"` should be captured and in turn replaced by `"zzyyyyxxx"`. I guess we may need two steps:

1. "capture": How to design the pattern to capture `"xxxyyyyzz"` (`"x"`,`"y"`,`"z"` are continuously repeated)?
2. "reverse": Howe to make `xxxyyyyzz` reversed such that we finally obtain a new string `"abzzyyyyxxxpqr"`?

Due to my limited knowledge about regex, I am not sure if `gsub` can finish this task **alone**. If possible, it would be appreciated to see how it can be implemented.

---

## More examples

I am after a ***generic regex***, not with specific characters:

- `"xxabcyyyzzpqr"` -> `"xxabczzyyypqr"`, where `"yyyzz"` should be the target
- `"xaaab,,,@@@&&"` -> `"xaaab&&@@@,,,"`, where `",,,@@@&&"` should be the target
- `"xxaaab,,,@@@&&"` -> `"aaaxxb&&@@@,,,"`, where both `"xxaaa"` and `",,,@@@&&"` should be the target

Comment: Do you mean a generic regex, or one that works particularly for those two given strings? If the latter, use [`(x*)(y+)(z+)`/`$3$2$1`](https://regex101.com/r/lYDzQP/2).

Comment: see my updated question with more input examples @InSync

Comment: Do you mean for arbitrary length or just up to three? For the latter an idea could be to replace [`((.)\2+)((?:(.)\4+)*)((?:(.)\6+))` with `$5$3$1`](https://regex101.com/r/hL8xRm/1).

Comment: @bobblebubble I meant for arbitrary, unfortunately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The matching part

...is trivial:

```
(         # Match a sequence consisting of
  (.)     # a letter
  \2+     # followed by 1 or more instances of that same letter
){2,}     # 2 or more times.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Op2Hus/2).

## The reversing part

...not so much.

According to [this page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/grep), the only special tokens allowed in the replacement string are backreferences, `\L` (**l**owercase conversion), `\U` (**u**ppercase conversion) and `\E` (**e**nd case conversion). This means that we don't even have access to PCRE conditional replacements (e.g. `${1:+foo:bar}`).

Since the replacement string can't provide us with anything useful, we need to somehow capture the reversed string in a group using only the pattern itself. However, as far as I know, capturing string X (into a single group) from string Y where X is not a substring of Y is not possible. Capturing into multiple groups is also not a choice, since we don't know how many groups we are going to need.

That said, reversing a substring using nothing else but `gsub()` is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer, now I know that `gsub` CANNOT do it, +1 already! I will keep the question open till tomorrow. If no new answers come up, I will accept yours, cheers!

Comment: Probably because I was unable to scientifically prove any proclamations :) If there is proof for them I would like to know too.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure about a single regex with `gsub`; however, this one-liner using `gsubfn` will do it.  `gsubfn` is like `gsub` except the replacement argument can be a function which accepts the match and capture groups replacing the match with the output of the function.  `backref=0` means input the entire match to the function but not the capture groups.  The function given in the second argument is specified using formula notation here.  We could alternately use `stringi::stri_reverse` as the second argument.

```
library(gsubfn)

s <- c("xxabcyyyzzpqr", "xaaab,,,@@@&&", "xxaaab,,,@@@&&")

gsubfn("(((.)\\3+)+)", ~ intToUtf8(rev(utf8ToInt(x))), s, backref = 0)
## [1] "xxabczzyyypqr"  "xaaab&&@@@,,,"  "aaaxxb&&@@@,,,"
```

It can alternately be written as the following where `&` means the entire match.  In that case we can omit the `backref=` argument.

```
gsubfn("(((.)\\3+)+)", ~ intToUtf8(rev(utf8ToInt(`&`))), s)
## [1] "xxabczzyyypqr"  "xaaab&&@@@,,,"  "aaaxxb&&@@@,,,"
```

Comment: Interesting feature by `gsubfun`, +1!  It seems that `gsub` itself is not strong enough to make it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function using `base` R to find continuously repeated characters.

```
find_continuously_repeated <- function(string){
  #Get each character that is not repeating
  single_character_string <- gsub("(.)\\1+", "", string , perl = TRUE)
  #Split into vector of characters to be used to split.
  single_chars <- strsplit(single_character_string, "")[[1]]
  #Create an empty list
  l<-list()
  
  #Use each single character to split the string
  for(i in 1:length(single_chars)){
    #Save the 1st element of split vector to list  
    l[[i]] <- regmatches(string, regexpr(single_chars[i], string), invert = TRUE)[[1]][[1]]
    #Save the 2nd element of split as the remainder
    string<- regmatches(string, regexpr(single_chars[i], string), invert = TRUE)[[1]][[2]]
    }
  #We now have a vector with of groups of repeated characters.
  groups<- c(unlist(l), string)
  
  #We can then output a vector from groups containing only ones with more than one unique character.
  output <- sapply(groups, function(x) {if(length(unique(strsplit(x, "")[[1]]))>1){x}}) |> unlist() |> as.vector()
  return(output)
}
```

Example usage:

```
s<-"xxaaab,,,@@@&&"
s<- find_continuously_repeated(s) 
> s
[1] "xxaaa"    ",,,@@@&&"
```

Or you can apply to a vector of strings:

```
input_strings <- c("xxabcyyyzzpqr",
                   "xaaab,,,@@@&&",
                   "xxaaab,,,@@@&&")

#Apply to a vector of strings 
sapply(input_strings, find_continuously_repeated )

$xxabcyyyzzpqr
[1] "yyyzz"

$`xaaab,,,@@@&&`
[1] ",,,@@@&&"

$`xxaaab,,,@@@&&`
[1] "xxaaa"    ",,,@@@&&"
```